# A Function chooses the maximum value among values in two or more labels

Tags: r, algorithm

this is the dummy data

```
df=structure(list(group1 = c("0.1531181", "0.1537821", "0.284066", 
"0.7549542", "0.2495559"), group2 = c("0.3116818", "0.5837542", 
"0.430886", "0.7856033", "0.6351635"), group3 = c(7.80191002743109e-17, 
2.22008198884117e-49, 4.64379480824993e-13, 0.0476184338005978, 
2.2062018808144e-39)), row.names = c("C4orf39", "FAM89A", "FMNL1", 
"CYB5R2", "CHST2"), class = "data.frame")
```

As you can see, the 'df' has three columns: group1, group2 and group3. Each of rows is gene name.

Now I want to build a function in R so that it will automatically detemine which value in either of the columns is maximum, and assign the group number to a new column 'GeneCluster'. The final result looks like:

------------------group1----------group2-----------GeneCluster

Gene1-----------(0.8)---------------(0.7)---------------------1

Gene2----------(-0.4)---------------(0.25)-------------------2

Of course the number of columns (groups) can be 2 or more.

Any helps would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, had to mess a little with the example to test

```
library(tidyverse)
df = structure(list(`group1` = c("0.1531181", "1", 
                                 "0.284066", "0.7549542", "0.2495559"), `group2` = c("0.3116818", 
                                                                                     "0.5837542", "0.430886", "0.7856033", "0.6351635")), row.names = c("C4orf39", 
                                                                                                                                                        "FAM89A", "FMNL1", "CYB5R2", "CHST2"), class = "data.frame")



df %>% 
  mutate(GeneCluster = if_else(group1 > group2,1,2))
```

Here is my second attempt should be general enough

```
set.seed(42)
df %>% 
  mutate_all(as.numeric) %>% 
  mutate(group3 = group2 * rnorm(5) + .5,
         row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-row) %>% 
  group_by(row) %>% 
  mutate(max_value = max(value),
         group_number = str_extract(name,"[:digit:]") %>% as.numeric(),
         group_max_value = if_else(value == max_value ,group_number,NA_real_)) %>%
  fill(group_max_value,.direction = c("updown")) %>%
  select(-group_number,-max_value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from = value)
```

Here is a new solution using the new version of dplyr

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(),as.numeric)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(result = c_across(contains("group")) %>% which.max())
```

Comment: Yeah, actually I also had the same solution. But the problem is, I am trying to build a function to do this task automatically, and it means the number of columns can be 3,4,.. or more

Comment: Oh ok, try to change the example to include  a third column please

Comment: Hey Bruno, I fixed the 'df' in the main question already. Please copy -paste once again in your R environment

Comment: Hey #Bruno, Many Thanks for your help. I will take a long time to understand your code lines but it is okay. I will try my best to do that (y) Thanks Again

Comment: No problem any questions feel free to ask, also look into the f1 button on rstudio for function documentation or ? function